# Query in c arrays

Tags: c

```
   int a[2]={1210,15};

    printf("%d",a[33] );
```

OUTPUT

```
1073828132
```

Why it's not throwing error when i'm trying to print `a[33]` even though the array element doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C does not do bounds-checking.

You will just be reading an arbitrary location in your [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Comment: You should probably also note the fact that this is true, but he's not getting a SEGFAULT because the memory he is leveraging is still a part of his application's stack.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C are just a sort-of syntactic sugar around pointers.

`int a[2]` creates the space for, and initializes, an array of 2 int's.

But `a[33]` is in fact `*(a + 33)`, with `a` just an `int *` pointing at the first element of `a`. When dereferencing the array, C doesn't care about the size the array was initialized to.